# Histogram with errorbars from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib

Data:

```
 [OrderedDict([(u'X1', 1), (u'X2', 21), (u'X3', 47), (u'X4', 18)]),
 OrderedDict([(u'X1', 25), (u'X2', 41), (u'X3', 16), (u'X4', 5)]),
 OrderedDict([(u'X1', 5), (u'X2', 23), (u'X3', 54), (u'X4', 5)]),
 OrderedDict([(u'X1', 0), (u'X2', 33), (u'X3', 43), (u'X4', 11)]),
 OrderedDict([(u'X1', 2), (u'X2', 41), (u'X3', 30), (u'X4', 14)]),
 OrderedDict([(u'X1', 16), (u'X2', 38), (u'X3', 22), (u'X4', 11)])]
```

How can I create a histogram with errorbars from this?
For example:
[image]

Simple histrogram from dict:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def histogram_plots(d,filename):
    X = np.arange(len(d))
    pl.bar(X, d.values(), align='center', width=0.5)
    pl.xticks(X, d.keys())
    ymax = max(d.values()) + 1
    pl.ylim(0, ymax)
    print d.keys()
    plt.savefig('..\histograms\\'+filename)  #  plt.savefig('.\histograms\\'+'_'.join(d.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right in the `pyplot.bar` [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar): You can simply pass your error bars with the `yerr` argument.